# How do I delete sub-directory regardless of parent folder name using powershell?

Tags: powershell

new to PS scripting so please bear with me.

I have the following folder structure - D:\Folder1, Folder2, Folder3....  Each parent folder has the same sub folder structure using yyyymmdd format (D:\Folder1\20221007).  I would like to use PS to delete any folders older than 90 days in any of these sub-folders.  We are always adding / removing parent folders.  I was using the below script but its getting unmanageable as the parent folders are changing more frequently.  I was thinking that I could list all the parent folders and pass them in and then loop through but not sure how best to do that.  I would also like to write the full path of all the folders that were deleted, if possible.

```
$DaysAgo = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-3)
$Folders = (Get-ChildItem "D:\Folder1" | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -Eq $True -And $_.Name -Match '^\d{8}'})
ForEach ($f In $Folders) {
    $FolderDate = Get-Date -Year $f.Name.SubString(0,4) -Month $f.Name.SubString(4,2) -Day $f.Name.SubString(6,2)
    If ($FolderDate -LT $DaysAgo) {
        Remove-Item $f.FullName -Recurse
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
$DaysAgo = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-3)
#Specify the switch parameter "-Directory", so get-childitem will only return directories. Also you can filter on the creation date of the directory
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "D:\Folder1" | Where-Object {$_.Name -Match '^\d{8}' -and $_.CreationTime -lt $DaysAgo}
#You can pass all paths to the parameter -path
$null = Remove-Item -Path $Folders.FullName -Confirm:$false -Force -recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$DaysAgo = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-3)
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory "D:\Folder*\*" 
ForEach ($f In $Folders) {
    try {
        $FolderDate = [Datetime]::ParseExact($f.Name, "yyyyMMdd", $null)
        If ($FolderDate -lt $DaysAgo) {
            Remove-Item $f.FullName -Recurse
        }
    } catch { }
}
```